# Fail to deploy to Github Pages - Blazor webassembly using GitHub Actions

Tags: blazor, github-actions

I think I have followed all the steps to deploy Blazor webassembly on GitHub Pages using GitHub Actions which I found from https://www.davideguida.com/how-to-deploy-blazor-webassembly-on-github-pages-using-github-actions/

But it failed at `Deploy to Github Pages` step

- Set up job (Passed)
- Run actions/checkout@v2 (Passed)
- Setup .NET Core (Passed)
- Publish with dotnet (Passed)
- Deploy to Github Pages (Failed)
- Post Run actions/checkout@v2 (Passed)
- Complete job (Passed)

Here are the error descriptions

```
    ❓ FAQ/Wiki: https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/wiki
     Support: https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/issues
    ⭐ Contribute: https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/blob/dev/CONTRIBUTING.md
    
    Maintained by James Ives (https://jamesiv.es)
Checking configuration and starting deployment… 
Deploying using …… 
Configuring git…
/usr/bin/git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/runner/work/FirstBlazor/FirstBlazor/.git/
/usr/bin/git config user.name ngaisteve1
/usr/bin/git config user.email xxx@gmail.com
/usr/bin/git remote rm origin
/usr/bin/git remote add origin ***github.com/ngaisteve1/FirstBlazor.git
/usr/bin/git fetch --no-recurse-submodules
From https://github.com/ngaisteve1/FirstBlazor
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Git configured… 
Starting to commit changes…
/usr/bin/git ls-remote --heads ***github.com/ngaisteve1/FirstBlazor.git master | wc -l
136e7850750d3861e72a15355289952f94777c9b    refs/heads/master
/usr/bin/git checkout --progress --force development
error: pathspec 'development' did not match any file(s) known to git
Running post deployment cleanup jobs… ️
/usr/bin/git worktree remove github-pages-deploy-action-temp-deployment-folder --force
fatal: 'github-pages-deploy-action-temp-deployment-folder' is not a working tree
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
Deployment failed! ❌
```

Here is my github repo - https://github.com/ngaisteve1/FirstBlazor

Comment: Ask to James Ives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a branch named `development` from `master` branch and set `development` branch as `default` branch in your repository settings.

This is because your `gh-pages.yml` files has `BASE_BRANCH: development` and `BRANCH: master`

```
with:
    ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
    BASE_BRANCH: development # The branch the action should deploy from.
    BRANCH: master # The branch the action should deploy to.
    FOLDER: build/wwwroot # The folder the action should deploy.
    SINGLE_COMMIT: true
```

so that deployment will happen from `development` branch to `master` branch